# AngularJS - Hide title, sidebarMeta, templateUrl depending on the return of the localStorage

Tags: javascript, angularjs

After the user logs in to the system, I store his data in a localStorage, within a service. Based on this, I need to set up a menu with the permissions of each user. Each menu item is in a BlurAdmin module.
I can recover the data, however I can not hide the link, if the user does not have the permission.
Here is the code:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('BlurAdmin.pages.dashboard', [])
        .config(routeConfig);

    /** @ngInject */
    function routeConfig($stateProvider) {

        $stateProvider
            .state('dashboard', {
                resolve: {
                    user: function(baSidebarService, $q){
                        var user = JSON.parse(baSidebarService.getStorage());
                        console.log(user)
                          var roles = ["GERENTE","ADMIN"];
                        user.roles.forEach(function(role){
                            if(roles.includes(role.nome)){
                                console.log('ok')
                            }
                            else{
                                return;
                            }
                        })                        
                    }
                },
                // if baSidebarService.getStorage() == true
                url: '/dashboard',
                templateUrl: 'app/pages/dashboard/dashboard.html',
                title: "Dashboard",                
                sidebarMeta: {
                    icon: 'ion-android-home',
                    order: 0,
                },
            });
    }

})();
```

Note that within the loop, I make a check if the user data is the same as the rules. The problem is that even though I check that they are different, I can not hide the Dashboard link. I already tried everything, with no success.

How could I do this, for example, depending on localStorage data:

```
                // if baSidebarService.getStorage() == true
                url: $scope.dashboard,
                templateUrl: $scope.template,
                title: $scope.title,                
                sidebarMeta: $scope.sidebar,
```

Comment: You're doing these checks inside of the route... so after someone has already clicked on the link. Can you use an `ng-show` or `ng-if` inside of the template to conditionally show the links based on what the value of `$resolve.user` is?

Comment: Sorry, I dont't understand

Comment: Do you have the template file for what is in `templateUrl: 'app/pages/dashboard/dashboard.html'`? Also, the code inside of `resolve` fires when someone is navigating to that page/state (after clinking on a link there) -- would it be better to prevent them from clicking on the link to begin with?